# pcre.index throwing TypeException:user error after using

Tags: monetdb

I'm trying to get the PCRE module working with my monetDB server.

I run the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pcre_index(s string, pattern string) RETURNS integer EXTERNAL NAME pcre."index";
```

But when I run the function:

```
select pcre_index('this is a long string', '\\s');
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeException:user.main[6]:'pcre.index' undefined in:     X_0:int := pcre.index(X_1:str, X_2:str);
```

I know other PCRE functions are working because when I run:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pcre_imatch(s string, pattern string) RETURNS boolean EXTERNAL NAME pcre."imatch";
select pcre_imatch('this is a long string', '\\b\\s');
```

I get the following:

```
+-------+
| %2    |
+=======+
| true  |
+-------+
```

I'm using [this](https://www.monetdb.org/documentation-Jan2022/dev-guide/monetdb-internals/mal-modules/strings/) link to derive the function that I should write.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong. I am using MacOS and have installed monetdb via homebrew.

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

You created your `pcre_index` in a correct way. The problem is that `pcre.index` requires a type `pcre` as its first parameter.

Use `pcre.patindex` instead:

```
sql>CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pcre_patindex(pat string, s string) RETURNS integer EXTERNAL NAME pcre."patindex";
operation successful
sql>select pcre_patindex('s', 'this is a long string');
+------+
| %2   |
+======+
|    4 |
+------+
1 tuple
sql>select pcre_patindex(R'\s', 'this is a long string');
+------+
| %2   |
+======+
|    0 |
+------+
1 tuple
```

**NB1:** with `pcre.index` and `pcre.patindex`, the pattern comes first.

**NB2** the `R''` syntax is preferable over the backslashes

**NB3** `pcre.(pat)index` uses an SQL pattern to try to match the string, not a PCRE regular expression.  That's why all those attempts with `\s` and `\b` fail: they're not SQL patterns. The interface to produce a PCRE value that could be used in `pcre.(pat)index` was removed in 2014.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Jennie. When I run the code in option #1 I get the following error:
`TypeException:user.main[5]:'calc.pcre' undefined in:     X_0:any := calc.pcre(X_1:str);`

For Option #2 is the first line of code supposed to be:
`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pcre_patindex(pattern pcre, s string) RETURNS integer EXTERNAL NAME pcre."patindex";`?

Comment: I removed Option 1, because it doesn't work.  Corrected the typo in Option 2, i.e. use `patindex`